# Optimizing access through two ForeignKeys from a select_for_update record

Tags: django, query-optimization

I have a Django (1.4.2) data model like so:

```
class CoreData(models.Model):
    cdid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=False)
    atr1 = # whatever
    atr2 = # whatever

class EnvironData(models.Model):
    cdid = models.ForeignKey(CoreData)
    # etc

class TransactionData(models.Model):
    edid = models.ForeignKey(EnvironData)
    # etc
```

I need to have an atomic transaction, in which I update the `etc` transaction data:

```
tdo = TransactionData.objects.select_for_update().get(etc=criteria)
# process transaction
# modify tdo object
tdo.save()
```

So far, so good. However, in the course of `process transaction`, I need to check `CoreData.atr1` and `CoreData.atr2`.

If I access those via `tdo.edid.cdid.atr{1,2}` then my understanding is that I'll have an extra read DB query because Django fetches the missing data. (To be honest, I'm not 100% sure it's just one; could also be two -- or even six but I would doubt that.)

On the other hand, if I combine `select_related()` with `select_for_update()` I will not only lock data which needs not (and shouldn't) be locked, I'll also create overhead for `tdo.save()`.

A third approach might be to fetch the data via an independent query (unrelated to `tdo`) which would be guaranteed to be a single DB query if `select_related()` is utilized. Plus, it could use `values()`.

I see this last approach as most efficient, also because the query can start with the `EnvironData` object whose `edid` I already have as `tdo.edid_id`.

Is my view justified? Is there an even better way?

*Update:* It is totally okay to access `tdo.edid.cdid.atr{1,2}` independently and even that they could change during the transaction, because they are independent of each other and it is not required that they maintain their value throughout the transaction. (Thank you @Uszy Wieloryba)

Comment: What did you end up doing? I've run into a similar situation, and I encounter an error in Postgres when I try to use `select_for_update` with `select_related`, not to mention I also worry about the performance of this (the locking is needed in one of my most widely used functions)... This is tricky stuff :/

Comment: @orokusaki Yes, this _is_ tricky stuff. I must admit I haven't optimized it yet, so living with the extra DB hit, which is currently not a performance problem. I never liked the combined `select_related`/`select_for_update` approach, thank you for your feedback. Looks like one should use the last approach, then. Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't, yet. My thoughts though: forget performance and strive for simplicity. If its an N+1 issue (select related), that is a big deal, but if its just 3-5 extra queries, I wouldn't sweat it. I'd rather select each record separately for update in a given view than have the mental overhead of, "I have to remember to test this when I update postgres", etc. if it becomes a real database problem, another (better?) solution could be to use cache.add(...) to lock the record. Google "using memcached to lock".

Answer (score 0):

If your `# process transaction` depends on `CoreData.atr1` and `CoreData.atr2`, perhaps they should be locked.

Comment: You're right to mention this possibility. There could be a race condition such that the transaction code sees an inconsistent state and fails. Interestingly, those two are independent of each other and it suffices to check that each of them fulfills a certain criteria at whatever point in time during the transaction. Admittedly, this is not always the case, in general.